# Relative URIs in html anchors - recommended/preferred way

Tags: html, uri, anchor

1. `<file_name>`

   ```html
   <a href="file.html">link</a>
   ```
2. `<slash><file_name>`

   ```html
   <a href="/file.html">link</a>
   ```
3. `<dot+slash><file_name>`

   ```html
   <a href="./file.html">link</a>
   ```

Which of these is recommended/preferred?
Do any of them impact the speed of retrieval?
What are the pros and cons when using either of them?

There's an extensive article on URLs by [skorks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639386/skorks) here: [What Every Developer Should Know About URLs](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/), but it does not give answers to any of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific recommendation.

The retrieval speed has no bearing on how the URI is constructed.

The only thing that you need to consider is whether the linking page and the page you are linking to are part of a group of pages - if you move them together then if your links are in style 2 they will break. If `file.html` will always be on the root of the site, then moving this file will make no difference.

I don't see the point of style 3.

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 is NOT the same as the others, because it resolves to the root of the website and not the current folder.

This question sounds suspiciously like [micro-optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html) to me, and the answer is fairly simple: The browser resolves the paths when a link is encountered, using the current URL or the `<base href="..." />` if one is provided. Therefore there is absolutely no difference.

Comment: Not even a micro-optimization.

Comment: Micro-optimization? Nothing like that on my mind. However thank you for the link (+1) - the article is quite useful. My question was asked to get the full view on the subject - I have never found someone mentioning recommendations for relative URI usage.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 and 3 produce the exact same HTTP GET request. Option 2 is different because a path starting with `/` will try to retrieve the file from the root rather than the current path.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reasonable difference between them in terms of speed/retrival.
- First and third are the same case: the resource named file.html resides in the same directory of the current file.
- In the second option "/file.html" means the file is located in the webroot of your application.
Here is explained [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)